# Why this has a solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x-1}}+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{2x-1}}=A\tag{1}$$
In general, given $A$, we can solve for $x$ as:
$$a=\sqrt{2x-1}$$
$$\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x-a}=A\Rightarrow2x+2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=A^2\Rightarrow2x-A^2=-2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$$
$$4x^2+A^4-4A^2x=4x^2-4a^2\Rightarrow A^4-4=x(4A^2-8)$$
$$x=\frac{A^4-4}{4A^2-8}=\frac14(A^2+2)\tag{2}$$
But when the original equation is set to equal $\sqrt{2}$:
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x-1}}+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{2x-1}}=\sqrt{2}\tag{3}$$
There is no solution for $x$, but suppose we set $A=\sqrt{2}$ in eq. $(2)$, we get:
$$x=\frac14\big((\sqrt{2})^2+2\big)\Rightarrow x=1$$

How is this possible? Have I made a mistake along the way?

Comment: Why do you think the equation with $\rm A= \sqrt 2 $ hasn't any solution? $x=1$ very well satisfies that.

Comment: Yes, given the general formula for $x$ in terms of $A$. But if you manually solve eq $(3)$, you will have no answer. By no answer I mean you get:$$1-2x=-2x+1$$

Comment: Please, check your maths. If you plug $x=1$ into your equation, you get $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1}}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{0}=\sqrt{2}$. So it is a solution for $A=\sqrt{2}$. So is $x=1/2$, btw., or any $x\in[1/2, 1]$. I don't know what you mean with "manually", I don't think you have done the rest of your calculations pedally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your solution in terms of $\rm A$.

You wrote $$x=\frac{A^4-4}{4A^2-8}=\frac14(A^2+2)$$

You cancelled the factor $A^2-2$, which isn't allowed, if $A=\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Great! Is there a special name for $A=\sqrt{2}$ here?

Comment: @JohnGlenn I don't know if there is a name for this... o_o

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x\ge\frac{1}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
A^2&=x+\sqrt{2x-1}+2\sqrt{x^2-(2x-1)}+x-\sqrt{2x-1}\\
&=2x+2\sqrt{(x-1)^2}
\end{align*}

If $x\ge 1$, $A^2=2x+2(x-1)=4x-2$ and hence $A=\sqrt{4x-2}$.

If $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$, $A^2=2x+2(1-x)=2$ and hence $A=\sqrt{2}$.

You missed the case when $A=\sqrt{2}$ in $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{2(x-\sqrt{2x-1}})=\cdots=|\sqrt{2x-1}-1|$$